# Galaxy S5 G900V startup failure with inconsistent symptoms making troubleshooting difficult

Tags: boot, samsung-galaxy-s-5, troubleshooting

My Samsung Galaxy S5 suddenly and quickly started deteriorating a few days ago. I did also install a software update from Verizon about a week ago, but what's odd is how the symptoms worsened gradually. (Why would software do that?)

- It started with occasional, random power-offs. No worries, I just rebooted.
- Later, some of those times I started seeing "SECURE FAIL: KERNEL" in red. 1 or 2 extra reboots, though, and I'd be good to go.
- Yesterday, the phone shut off a few times, taking more reboots to get things going.
- Now, sometimes the power button doesn't respond (not even the vibration). When it does, sometimes nothing shows up on the display. If a display shows, it might hang on the *Samsung GALAXY S5 "Powered by Android"* loading screen—but that's not as common.<sup>*</sup> More common is simply going to that "SECURE FAIL: KERNEL" screen. I've been rebooting for an hour now—probably 20+ times—with no success in getting a full boot.

<sup><sup>*</sup> This screen actually says "Custom" as well, with an unlocked padlock icon. But I've never rooted a phone, nor done anything "custom." I read something about ART vs. Dalvik and that it's normal for this phone. Plus, that started showing up months ago, so I'm guessing it's unrelated.</sup>

**Given the variety of symptoms—from the power button not responding to this "SECURE FAIL: KERNEL" message, and also the *gradual* degrading of successful reboot attempts, am I correct to conclude that this is more likely a hardware issue than software, *e.g.* the update to Lollipop, if that's what it was?**

Some other notes that may contain clues for the more experienced:

- I did manage to get into recovery mode once, and wiped the cache.
- The other two attempts left me with a screen saying "SECURE FAIL: RECOVERY".
- Sometimes the phone seems to start up by itself after 10+ minutes of not being touched, having a black display, and no indicator lights.
- While plugged in and in the above state, I don't see the green battery charging animation. Maybe that means it's not really "off" but stuck in some software block or loop.
- Once I did see the battery animation, and the battery was at 88%, so I think the battery's okay.
- This is a S5 G900V that I purchased new from Verizon in October 2015.

I wish it would start up properly just *once* so I can get some data off the phone's memory.

---

An interesting development.

While typing this post, it got past "SECURE FAIL: KERNEL", but froze at the Samsung logo animation. Then, the display went black, while the blue indicator light stayed on. A few minutes later, the phone restarted itself, passed the *Powered by Andoird* screen as it usually does, and hit "SECURE FAIL: KERNEL." I rebooted again, and saw something I saw only once before, "SECURE FAIL: Modem."

Comment: At this point I've not only wiped the cache but also done a factory / data reset—same problem.

Comment: Can you still get into the download mode(Power+Volume Down while device is off)? If so, I would try to flash a stock firmware image onto your device. You can download the firmware [at sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G900V/). Download the newest one and follow the instructions given on the download page. Your data won't be deleted but you'll get a fresh system image onto your device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with all the symptoms you documented. It reads like I would have written it. It seems many of us are suffering from the same phone issue. Ultimately I ended up sending the phone to Samsung. They returned it unrepaired and stated the cost for repair would be unjustifiable.

Apparently, though, it can be repaired. I called Samsung, and, of course, talked to someone "who knows where". She did try and did say that an S7 root driver was installed into my S6. She said I could have done this while connected to my PC. Nope, the phone auto-downloads updates.

I don't understand why they cannot reflash the chip. I don't understand how I could be responsible for this and why I should have to purchase a new phone.

Personally, I think Samsung sent the update without safeguarding that an older model would not auto-download it. I think it's their fault and they are not taking responsibility. I didn't do this and now it's out of warranty, because of this unauthorised flash, irreparable due to cost. I'm screwed, we're screwed.

Comment: Agreed. I was forced to buy a new phone in the end as well, and it's utterly frustrating that we have no power to argue against them.